# Effect of changing screen orientation on the soft keyboard

Tags: android

The problem is that I switch the screen orientation on a particular activity to landscape mode, and when I click an edit text the soft keyboard only displays a part of it(the line of the top). In portrait mode there is no problem, so I assume this is a problem related to the screen orientation.How do I fix this?
I'm using android 2.2 platform.

Android Manifest code for the activity:

```
<activity android:name=".Main"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation = "landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Code for the EditText on the layout:

```
<EditText  
    android:id = "@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/text"
    android:inputType = "text"
    />
```

Comment: I think that's by design.  They increased the size of all the keys, but kept the keyboard wider than it is tall, leaving much less room at the top for text, so they only show one line.

Comment: When I said the top of it, I meant an empty grey line, showing me nothing...,if this is a design problem, then users can't type in phones without hard keyboard on landscape mode,Mmmmmm, that's too odd.